# giving the error while importing the timestamp

Tags: python, pandas

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-2e240bbfe4e9> in <module>
----> 1 df = pandas.TimeStamp.now()
      2 df
NameError: name 'pandas' is not defined
```

Comment: you need to import pandas if you are using its methods

Comment: And if you do something like `import pandas as pd`, you need to write `pd.TimeStamp.now()`

Answer (score 0):

did you tried import pandas first ?

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp
```